# exclude inputbox default text, only take user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, inputbox

I have a couple of checkboxes and an inputbox. User can either tick the checkboxes or/and also type a keyword. If user doesn't type anything in the input box, only checkboxes values should be passed to the url. if user types in sth in the inout box, it should also pass the input box value. Well in my case, it is also grabbing the default text "enter keyword" in the inputbox. How do i exclude that and only take user inputs?

```
<div class="LocationSearchBox">
    <input name="KeywordBox" class="BasicSearchInputBox" type="text" size="300" value="Enter Keyword"/> 
    <div class="searchBtnHolder"><a class="searchButton" href="#" type="submit"><span>Search</span></a></div>
</div>
```

I am this far..

```
if (keywords.indexOf("Enter Keywords"))
                 {
                    window.location= url+checkboxValues;
                 }

                if (keywords.indexOf("Enter Keywords") == -1)
                 {
                    window.location= url+keywords+'*'+checkboxValues;
                 }
```

Comment: Whoever gave me a -ve rating to my question must be the wisest person in the world!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider emptying the default value onfocus and assigning it back onblur if its value is empty?

```
var keyW = $("input[name='KeywordBox']");
keyW.data('initVal',keyW.val());
keyW.focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).data('initVal')) $(this).val('');
});
keyW.blur(function() {
    if (/^\s*$/.test($(this).val())) $(this).val($(this).data('initVal'));
});
```

Comment: How is this gonna help me?? I don't wanna capture the default text I wanna exclude it, and only grab user inputs. I am not trying to hide the default text on focus and show it on out of focus..

Comment: This will clear the default text when user focuses the input field. Try and see the result.

Comment: what if user doesn;t type anything but just checks the checkboxes? I only want to pass checkboxes values but not the input box values, which will be "enter keywords" since user didn't type any keywords?

Comment: You can check whether the value of the text input equals the data **initVal** before deciding to take its value into account, along with the values of checked checkboxes, if any.